# Right outer join not getting same results dont know why (=*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, helper

Hi all new to database outer join and inner join modified below code from

```
FROM leaf_star_stem_bud, leaf_star_item, cosmic_tank 
WHERE leaf_star_stem_bud.power_company_key  =  '6aa5' 
      And leaf_star_item.parent_key = 'eaab1' 
      And cosmic_tank.master_key = leaf_star_item.cost_code_key 
      And leaf_star_stem_bud.parent_key  =*  leaf_star_item.master_key
```

to

```
FROM leaf_star_stem_bud 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN leaf_star_item ON 
     leaf_star_stem_bud.parent_key = leaf_star_item.master_key , cosmic_tank 
WHERE leaf_star_stem_bud.power_company_key  =  '6aa5' 
       And leaf_star_item.parent_key = 'eaab1'
       And cosmic_tank.master_key = leaf_star_item.cost_code_key
```

but the query is not getting the same results could you please help me out

Comment: If you use join, you have to join all columns. Do not mix join and where for `cosmic_tank `

Comment: use proper INNER JOIN syntax for `cosmic_tank` as well

Comment: Jen then you say that they modification of syntax is completely wrong way of doing

Comment: I only made sure that =* is modified to RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

*INNER JOIN* or *JOIN* or *,* :

- Give me all *leaf_star_stem_bud* which has a *leaf_star_item* associated to it.

---

*RIGHT JOIN* or *RIGHT OUTER JOIN*:

- Give me all *leaf_star_stem_bud* which has a *leaf_star_item* associated to it.
- If there are more *leaf_star_item*, give me them and complete *leaf_star_stem_bud* info with *null*.

---

*LEFT JOIN* or *LEFT OUTER JOIN*:

- Give me all *leaf_star_stem_bud* which has a *leaf_star_item* associated to it.
- If there are more *leaf_star_stem_bud*, give me them and complete *leaf_star_item* info with *null*.

---

For more information:

[What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)